# Refine discussion list

Tags: filter

I am using a Community site and I need to refine my discussion list.

I added a column with multiple choice.

I would like to add a combobox with the possibility to filter for that column.

How can this be done?
I do not have access to share point designer.
Thank you

Comment: Cdonó - are you by chance Carla under a different account? I noticed your edit and wondered if you created a new account since the Carla one seem to be unregistered. If that is the case, you probably could use an account merge. I have leaved a notice to the mods about this, if you need a merge just post a notice here to confirm you are the same user.

Comment: Do you want the account merged?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter web part to filter a multiple-choice column on a single value. However, list view web parts don't support the "Allow multiple selections" option of the filter settings.

However, you should be able to build your own filter inputs and logic by creating a Custom Data View in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by creating views and adding filters according with what you want to do.

Here are some links, but you can find more in Google.

- Creating views:
  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-modify-or-delete-a-view-10c68afb-d901-4b15-848b-82d399eba089
- Filtering a view:
  http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/11/understanding-filters-in-sharepoint-list-views-aspx/

Bests regards.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to filter a list by multiple values.